# How can you call custom fields in an override for com_contacts

Tags: overrides, custom-field, contact, com-contacts

In `com_content` I can call my fields one by one as follows

```
<?php echo $this->item->jcfields[3]->value; ?>
```

The same code does not work in `com_contacts`.  How can I call the fields in a custom override in `com_contacts`?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($this->item);`?

Comment: If I do that I get `null`

Comment: I also get `null` if I `var_dump` `$params`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this helpful, I did.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Overrides

It has been years, but if you examine your array you will find the proper value of [#]. You can then modify your code.

Add this at the bottom of your override to see the contents of the array:

snippet: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: I already know about this. Did you use it on com_contact?

Comment: Ah I think you helped me.  I see the array now which made me realise my field is in fact a multiple select list, so an array within an array.